# jquery/javascript: replace string inside of html()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

the following variable …

```
var breadcrumbs = $('#trail').html();
```

… contains:

`<href="page1/">Page 1</a> <strong>»</strong> <a href="page2">Page 2</a> <strong>»</strong> <a href="page3">Page 3</a>`

How can I replace each `<strong>»</strong>` with something else?

Comment: Generally it would be better to do such manipulations as DOM elements instead of as a String. Could you describe what you're ultimately trying to do?

Comment: Well whatever. Just be wary of subtle changes to the HTML string returned by `.html()` in some browsers that will break the `.replace()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just a regular old `replace` should do it. Be careful about `»`, it might be written as `&raquo;` in the markup or something...

```
breadcrumbs.replace( new RegExp("<strong>»</strong>", 'g'), "something else" );
```

Comment: Sidenote: `»` really _should be_ written as `&raquo;` in your markup.

Answer (score 5):

```
breadcrumbs.replace("<strong>»</strong>","new string");
```

or, depending on how you have written the » character

```
breadcrumbs.replace("<strong>&raquo;</strong>","new string");
```

Comment: The difference between this and my answer is that this will only replace a single instance in the `breadcrumbs` string.

Comment: You hadn't answered when I posted my answer. We must have posted at the same time.

Comment: Yea, it happens. Just wanted to point out the differences in our code for the asker.